# How to strip a string in PHP from everything besides numbers

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

Currently when I `echo` a string I have saved it looks like this:

> • 94% positive ·

What I want to have instead is simply:

> 94

I thought that the following would do the trick:

> preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $string)

But for some reason (I am assuming the bullet point) doing so instead gives me this:

> 94018332

Any help to get just the "94"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the bullet point is being handled as an HTML entity and therefore contains numbers.

However, since your format is specific enough, you can use a better regex:

```
preg_match("/\d+(?=%)/",$string,$match);
$percentage = $match[0];
```

This regex specifically searches for numbers followed immediately by a percent sign (and only the first such match).

Comment: But  how could a HTML encoded percent sign ever result in `94018332`?

Comment: @Pekka웃 It has nothing to do with the percent sign, and everything to do with the middot. I'm not sure how middot and `018332` go together, but it's possible that there's more than one special character there (such as spaces)

Comment: Ah, you're right. I got stuck on the `%` for some reason

Comment: Would the two people who downvoted this answer please explain?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the filter functions to filter the number out.

```
$yourString =  "• 94% positive";
$int = filter_var($yourString, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo $int; //WIll echo 94
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://codepad.org/yBgBeXIl)</kbd>

Comment: This is functionally identical to the original code, and therefore will not work due to the middot special character.

Comment: Your demo show's a full stop, not the html bullet.

Comment: Either way it should just work

Comment: It'll still work: http://codepad.org/yBgBeXIl

Comment: @webnoob, that is just for demo. I didn't wanted to look for unicode character for that.

Comment: Yeah, just checked it myself. Still good then :)

Comment: If you actually try rebuilding the original string, you get [this](http://codepad.org/9AGsbSny) and lo and behold it doesn't work.

Comment: @Starx but the middot is fundamental here. If the string consists of numeric HTML entities (which is why the problem occurs in the first place), those numbers will be (incorrectly) filtered out as well.

Comment: @Pekka웃, Now I understand the problem. Kolink's answer is good for that I think.

Comment: *How does this answer have five upvotes???*

Comment: @Kolink, I upvoted your answer, as it is the right one.

Comment: @devirkahan You should accept Kolink's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your number is always on the first and following characters you can use functions like [`floatval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) or `intval`.

Answer (score -1):

Did you simply try to cast?

```
echo (int) trim("• 94% positive ·", "•  ·");
echo (int) trim("• 94% positive", "•  ·");
```

Both should output to:

```
94
```

Kind regards...